# Show data in different order on page than in database

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I can't figure out how can I manage to show some data from a database in different order on the page.
In my case I have a table with three columns: Day of week, Open from, and Open to, so its basically an open hours for specific days of week. In my database table I have it like this:

1. Sunday     00:00  00:00
2. Monday     07:00  15:00
3. Tuesday    07:00  15:00
4. Wednesday  07:00  15:00
5. Thursday   07:00  15:00
6. Friday     07:00  15:00
7. Saturday   00:00  00:00

But on my page I want to show it like the first one is Monday, second is Tuesday and so on. What I can do now is that the days are in right position but the time for them are still the same as in the database.

I'm using Angular as frontend, Springboot as backend.

I just need an easy solution if possible, can provide code if needed.

```
regularDays: RegularDays[];
  RegDay: RegularDays = new RegularDays("", "", "", "");

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private httpClientService: RegularDaysService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClientService.getRegularDays().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.regularDays = response;
        this.regularDays.forEach(element => {
          element.openFrom = this.formatTime(element.openFrom);
          element.openTo = this.formatTime(element.openTo);
          element.dayOfWeek = this.formatDay(element.dayOfWeek);
        });
      }
    );
  }

formatDay(day) {
    let formattedDay = "";
    switch (day) {
      case '1': formattedDay = 'Monday'

        break;
      case '2': formattedDay = 'Tuesday'

        break;
      case '3': formattedDay = 'Wednesday'

        break;
      case '4': formattedDay = 'Thursday'

        break;
      case '5': formattedDay = 'Friday'

        break;
      case '6': formattedDay = 'Saturday'

        break;
      case '7': formattedDay = 'Sunday'

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return formattedDay;
  }
```

Comment: Please show what you've done so far in the frontend.

Comment: added code for frontend

Comment: What does the backend response look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   daysOrder = { Sunday: 1, Monday: 2, Tuesday: 3, Wednesday: 4, Thursday: 5, Friday: 6, Saturday: 7 };

   this.regularDays.sort(function (a, b) {
        return daysOrder[a.dayOfWeek] - daysOrder[b.dayOfWeek];
    });
   console.log('regularDays:',this.regularDays);
```